# $sth->execute() returning false

Tags: php, pdo, execute

I have this code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
$sth = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT `login`, `password` FROM `admins` WHERE `login` = ?, `password` = ? ");
var_dump($sth->bindParam(1, $login)); // true
var_dump($sth->bindParam(2, $password)); // true
var_dump($sth->execute()); // false
```

Comment: Dump `$sth->errorInfo()` after you call `execute()`; it should give you information regarding the failure.  If you can't figure out the problem using that information, add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE `login` = ?, `password` = ?
```

shouldn't that be...

```
WHERE `login` = ? and `password` = ?
```